# Out of Memory Exception?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I wrote this code but got out of memory exception in the line if I am passing the range value 46542.

```
long[,] array = new long[range, range];
```

How to resolve this?

```
int noOfTestCases = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
if(noOfTestCases>=1 && noOfTestCases<=100)
{
    for(int i=0; i<noOfTestCases; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Range");
        long range = Convert.ToInt64(Console.ReadLine());
        long[,] array = new long[range, range];
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `range`?

Comment: Why do you want to create an array of 2,166,157,764 elements then?

Comment: more than 46542 or may be less then some values to the 46542.

Comment: I think you need more memory

Answer (score 3):

> How to resolve this?

Choose a range that is smaller than 46,341.  The largest number of *elements* in an array is `Int32.MaxValue`, or 2,147,483,647.

Since you're creating an NxN array, the largest size of one side of the "square" is `Math.Sqrt(Int32.MaxValue)` or `46340.950001052`.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum size you can have as an indexer in an array is `System.Int32.MaxValue`, which is smaller than some `Int64` numbers. Hence you get this exception.